# Protocol not available error for scp on Linux

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, scp

I'm trying to copy windows file to linux, but the scp command always see 'Protocol not available', bellow is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
client_IP='192.168.0.47'
windows_log_folder='E:\project\robot_framework\第一个测试项目\logs'
argfile_path='E:\project\robot_framework\第一个测试项目\logs\argfile.txt'
time_folder=`date +%Y-%m-%T`
echo ${time_folder}
base_path=$1
echo $base_path
log_folder="${base_path}/logs/${time_folder}"
mkdir "${log_folder}"
echo "${log_folder}"
echo "baimng.zhang@${client_IP}:${argfile_path}"
scp -p baiming.zhang@${client_IP}:${argfile_path} '${log_folder}'
ssh baiming.zhang@${client_IP} "pybot.bat --argumentfile ${argfile_path} E:\project\robot_framework\第一个测试项目" #works fine

files=`ssh baiming.zhang@${client_IP} "dir /b /a:-D ${windows_log_folder}"`
for file in $files
do
   path="${windows_log_folder}\\${file}"
   echo $path
   scp -p baiming.zhang@${client_IP}:${path} '${log_folder}' #**error appears  in this line**
done
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a whitespace in the file name which I get from the windows command, I use below code the trim the file name, then it works fine.

```
for file in $files
do
    new_file="$(echo -e "${file}" | tr -d '[:space:]')"
    path=${folder}${new_file}
    path="${windows_log_folder}\\${new_file}"
    echo "try to copy ${path} to ${log_folder}"
    scp -p baiming.zhang@${client_IP}:${path} ${log_folder}
done
```